# Remote JNDI lookup - refresh cached objects

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, jndi

I am using JNDI lookup in order to locate a remote JMS connection factory and queue. The lookup happens at application startup and then I cache these objects for further use.

Everything works fine until I restart the remote JMS server where the connection factory and queue reside. After the JMS server restart the application is not able to create JMS connections anymore, it just hangs in `connectionFactory.createConnection()`. The only way I could fix this by restarting the application we well.

My question is: do I need to refresh these JNDI objects (connection factory + queue) after I detect that the JMS Server has been restarted?

Comment: The JMS server is not a JNDI server. I would get rid of the cache. It doesn't buy you anything except trouble.

Comment: Ok, maybe I didn't use the proper terminology - so the JMS server is not a JNDI server. Creating the initial context and then the objects lookup is a resource consuming task - you say I should never cache these objects?

Comment: That's exactly what I already said. The 'resources consumed' are negligible: it all happens in memory.

Comment: Whenever you have code that is communicating with remote services you need to write it in a way that can deal with that service going offline and subsequently becoming available again.